# intersection of rows in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, arraylist, intersection

I have the following lists in python:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
b = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```

I want to intersect a with each row of b. For this something like

```
d = set(a).intersection(set(b[0]), set(b[1]), set(b[2]))
```

will work but I want iterative method because if the number of rows in b increases then writing all of them like this is too much. Also if I take many rows in a then intersecting corresponding rows of a and b would also require iteration. What do we do.

I checked intersections but usually they give the intersection of only 2 or 3 or 4 sets. What about intersection say 128 sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
d = set(a).intersection(*b)
```

`b` here just has to be an iterable so it can yield as many items as your system / the implementation allows!  From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

> ...the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(), difference(),
> symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset() methods will
> accept any iterable.

The `*` here is the **iterable unpacking** operator ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists)) which

> expand[s] [the iterable] into a sequence of items, which are included
> in the new tuple, list, or set, at the site of the unpacking.

With `a` and `b` as defined in your question, printing `d` would yield output

```
{3}
```

just as expected.

Hope this helps! Please let me know if there are any questions!